# Eclipse exported jar file just shows a black Jpanel

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, executable-jar

I am working on a java game and the game works perfectly in eclipse, but when I exported is as a runnable jar file it did not work. Only a black window showed up.

My game has a splash screen which changes to menu screen after few seconds. the splash screen sconsists of an BufferedImage (in jpg) but the menu screen also consists of a Graphics2D writing. Few seconds after running the jar file the writing doesn't show up, so I think image formats and such might not be the issue.

I'm quite confused and frustrated so any help would be appriciated.

---

It turned out the problem is in my use of Timer, this is my source of the splashscreen

```
  package GameState;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import Main.GamePanel;

public class SplashState extends GameState implements ActionListener{



private BufferedImage image;
private Timer timer;

public SplashState(GameStateManager gsm) {

    this.gsm = gsm;
     try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Resources/Backgrounds/block.jpg"));
        timer = new Timer(2000, this);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start(); 
     } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void init() {

}

public void update() {

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    g.drawImage(image, (GamePanel.WIDTH-image.getWidth())/2, (GamePanel.HEIGHT-image.getHeight())/2, null);

}


public void keyPressed(int k) {

}
public void keyReleased(int k) {}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENUSTATE);
timer.stop();
}

}
```

I still don't know what's wrong so any help would be appriciated

Comment: Is the image included inside the jar? Because if it is not that might be a problem, I don't know about the writing :/.

Comment: Yes, I made a resources folder full of packages of images, but this worked for my other projects so I don't think it is the case

Comment: Ok weird, this might be a silly idea but it worked for me once try running your jar with a .bat file (or .sh).

Comment: Didn't help, nothing deifferent happened

Comment: Aw ok just to be sure did you check if all you files are exported by entering the jar? Else I don't know anymore sorry :/

Comment: Found this though you might find something usefull here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057731/why-is-my-jframe-just-a-black-window

Comment: Actually, I found out that the colour of the blank window is the same as the color of the graphics2D background color, so I think something happenes, but afterwards it throws a wierd exception the code can't handle. I think it actually might be a files issue, since til now I have been using only gifs and txts and now I also use pngs and jpgs. Is there any difference in storing them??

Comment: Not really if they are inside the jar and correctly pointed to there should not be a difference in loading them. I asume you load things inside a jar via classloader right? By the way wich exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem in the past, and it was due to the way Eclipse was packaging the required libraries into the jar.  I would bet you have it set to "Extract required libraries into generated jar", and you should set it to "Package required libraries into generated jar".  To do this, right click on project -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar File.  Then click next, and select the radio button for "Package required libraries into generated jar".  This should fix your problem.

If you are writing to an image, the image must be outside of the jar file, because you cannot edit a jar file while it is running.  If this is the case, you may want to make a folder that contains your jar and the images it will write to.

Comment: it didn't work, I've tried that already. And also I am only using an image, not writing to it

Comment: could it be possible that your eclipse vm is using different parameters than your system vm? Or maybe your Eclipse java version is different from your system version?